# Heap profile graph has perfectly linear tail

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm struggling to understand heap graphs that look like the following:

[image: heap graph]

In particular, I'm a bit baffled by the very regular looking tail of the graph (from 100.0s to the end). Am I to understand that the heap size decreased perfectly linearly? Is this a known issue with `+RTS -h -RTS`?

This graph was generated with

```
$ cabal new-build --enable-profiling --ghc-options "-rtsopts -O2"
$ $(find dist-newstyle -type f -name haddock) +RTS -h -p -RTS ...
$ hp2ps -c haddock.hp
```

Comment: It looks as if the last sample was taken at ~80s, and then a "zero" point was added at the very end. I would not trust that tail.

Comment: @chi Yeah, I don't. But why is this happening in the first place?

Comment: No real idea. Is the process just sitting idle for a very long time? Maybe if no memory is allocated the RTS won't generate new samples (?)

Comment: If I take off `-h` and just look at the `.prof` file, looks like runtime really is ~80s. This is definitely a bit confusing.

Comment: Seems to be a glitch in plotting.